Put text at the right of checkbox
I try to build UI for labels and checkboxes dynamically
My idea is to build it like this


function renderCheckbox(ui, uiField, labelText, idField, nameOnForm){
    let id = abp.helper.getUniqueElementId();
    let container  = $('<div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">');
    let label = $('<label class="m-checkbox mt-35px">').attr('for', idField).text(labelText);
    let checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox" class="filter">').attr('name', nameOnForm).attr('id', idField);
    checkbox.appendTo(label);
    let result = container.append(label);

    return result;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <label for="HideVerifiedTickets" class="m-checkbox mt-35px">
            <input id="HideVerifiedTickets" class="filter" type="checkbox" name="HideVerifiedTickets" />
            HideVerifiedTickets
            <span></span>
        </label>
    </div>



but the problem is that it generates HTML like this

How can I move text after the checkbox?

Instead of checkbox.appendTo(label);, just use checkbox.prependTo(label); ...?

You could style the label to be a row-reverse flexbox

As you're using for= you don't need to nest the checkbox inside the label, so container.append(checkbox).append(label); return container;

@fdomn-m  got your point. Correct.

You can create a textNode using the createTextNode() method and append it to the label just like you do with the checkbox.
In the example I removed the for attribute and the ID for the input element because they are probably not needed.


let cb1 = renderCheckbox(null, null, 'Test', 'test');

$(document.forms.form01).append(cb1);

function renderCheckbox(ui, uiField, labelText, nameOnForm) {
  let container = $('<div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">');
  let label = $('<label class="m-checkbox mt-35px">');
  let checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox" class="filter">').attr('name', nameOnForm);
  checkbox.appendTo(label);
  let text = $(document.createTextNode(labelText));
  text.appendTo(label);
  container.append(label);

  return container;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form01">
</form>




why creating an extra variable and assigning the whole HTML to it and then return it?

@Death-is-the-real-truth I'm not sure that I understand your question 100%, but when I answer a question I often try to get my answer including example code as close to what OP has in the question. If you refer to the let cb1 variable, this is just for testing. As you can read from the question, OP has many checkboxes to insert, so in the production code there is probably some loop that calls the renderCheckbox function -- what that looks like, we don't know. My answer just focus on getting the function to return the right value and making the code as transparent/understandable as possible.

I ama asking about these lines `let result = container.append(label);
return result;`
